# How to write half billion entries to neo4j in a reasonable time (less than 1 day)?

Tags: python, performance, neo4j, cypher, bigdata

I am processing a large amount of e-mails’ data and would like to load all into a neo4j DB.

The idea is to allocate a node per address and edges for each email was sent between two or more addresses.

```
from py2neo import Graph,Node,Relationship,authenticate
graph = Graph()
tx = graph.begin()

# doing the following in batches of 100 and then commit
a = Node("E-mail_subject", name=str(num))
b = Node("Address", name=dest_addr)
tx.merge(a, "E-mail_subject", "name")
tx.merge(b, "Address", "name")
ba = Relationship(b, "WAS_ON", a, time=t, name=num, weight=w, _id=tx_hash)
tx.create(ba)

# commit every 100 relations
tx.commit()
```

The above takes ages to load 500 millions emails to neo4j. Any suggestion how to do it faster?

Comment: It is hard to say, you are committing in batches, I would probably increase the number as long as you are not going over the amount of ram you have.  But you didn't mention how long adding 500 million emails takes.  I am guessing around 2 hours is ages?

Comment: @NiteRain a few weeks!

Comment: how much memory was being consumed during running of this?  Try increasing your batching; try starting at 10k and see how well that performs, and increase it if you notice the memory is fine.  You can see how things progress every hour when the commit happens, so you can figure out how long it will take with your current batch setting.

Comment: @NiteRain I have 64GB running neo4j as a container.

Comment: I don't have much experience with py2neo but definitely increase the size of the batch from 100 to something like 100.000

Comment: see: https://medium.com/neo4j/5-tips-tricks-for-fast-batched-updates-of-graph-structures-with-neo4j-and-cypher-73c7f693c8cc

Answer (score 0):

why not use import csv.  gonna be a heck of a lot faster!

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000 LOAD CSV FROM EMAIL_CSV_FILE  as line merge
(:E-mail_subject{name:line[0]}) 

USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000 LOAD CSV FROM ADDRESS_CSV_FILE  as line
merge (:Address{name:line[0]}) 

USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000 LOAD CSV FROM WAS_CSV_FILE  as line merge 
(:E-mail_subject{name:line[0]}) -[:WAS_ON{time=line[2], name=line[3],
weight=line[4], _id=line[5]}]-(:Address{name:line[1]})
```

Comment: Why rewriting my data as csv will be faster than writing it directly to neo4j?

Comment: What if I create a data frame in pandas before submitting the batch to neo4j?

Comment: Well @ox90 with cvs you can get about 10 million nodes into neo within about 3 minutes on just a regular machine.   I don't really want to copy paste from neo the exact internal process for import csv  ( here's just one example)(https://neo4j.com/blog/import-10m-stack-overflow-questions/)

Comment: then you can also use call apoc.periodic.iterate('call apoc.load.json("file-url")', 'create/merge ... value.name, ...', {batchSize:100000, iterateList:true})`

Comment: It's incredible how sporadic and disassembled the neo4j documentation is, probably the worst I've ever found.